# Quick method /Birds eye view to determine the value

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Is there any way to guess the answer without doing elaborating calculations?

Comment: Apparently I have misread your question (I've read y instead of xy). So what my previous answer shows is that y can only be 1, 2 or 3. See updated version.

Comment: So you typed "with elaborate calculations" but context suggest you meant "without". Which is it?

Comment: sorry I edited it, it was without

Comment: @ComplexGuy OK! I was going to say that I could think up far more elaborate calculations than the answers already given, if need be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Corrected after a comment of André Nicolas**:

We have $4^5=1024>1016$. This shows that $y$ can only be $1$, $2$ or $3$. Now if $y=3$, then since $3^2\times 3^5>1016$, the only possible values of $x$ are $1$ and $2$. Similarly, if $y=2$, the only possible values of $x$ are $1,2,3,4,5$. Computing the products $xy$ and comparing them with the values proposed in the question, out of these seven options there remain only two: $(x,y)=(2,2)$ and $(x,y)=(5,2)$. Checking for $z^3$, out of these two possibilities there remains only one: $(x,y,z)=(5,2,6)$.

Now if $y=1$, then $xy=x$, and all we have to check is: which of the six values among $1016-(xy)^2$ are cubes. This gives one more triple $(x,y,z)=(4,1,10)$.

So the possible values of $xy$ (among indicated) are $4$ and $10$.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @ComplexGuy  well, $x^2y^5+z^3>x^2y^5>y^5$. So if $4^5>1016$, then...

Comment: So the answer is only 4?

Comment: so the options are wrong?

Comment: I Got it now. :-)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have misread the question ($y$ instead of $xy$). Feel free to post your answer or I will modify mine.

Comment: @ComplexGuy Because if $x\geq6$, then (for $y=2$) one has $x^2y^5\geq36\times 32>1016$.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solutions are 4 and 10. Denoting $f(x,y,z) = x^2y^5 + z^3$,

```
x   y   z   f(x,y,z)   xy
5   2   6   1016       10
4   1   10  1016       4
```

Here is the PERL code used to get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $z = 1;
my ($y5, $z3);

while (($z3 = $z**3) < 1016) {
    my $x2y5 = 1016 - $z3;
    my $y = 1;
    while (($y5 = $y ** 5) <= $x2y5) {
        next if $x2y5 % $y5;
        my $x2 = $x2y5 / $y5;
        if (int(sqrt($x2)) ** 2 == $x2) {
            my $x = int(sqrt($x2));
            print "($x, $y, $z) -> ", ($x**2) * ($y**5) + ($z**3), "; ", $x*$y, "\n";
        }
    } continue {
        $y++;
    }
} continue {
    $z++;
}
```

Comment: Dear Vedran: I commend your effort and ability with the code, but the original question asks for a way to find the answer through estimates without doing elaborate computations. The OP looks a little bit like it comes from a paper test where you sit down and have a minute or two for each question. I think the user would not have time or resources to implement and run a perl script to solve the problem...

Comment: @rschwieb The post of Vedran Sego was partly intended to correct my initially wrong (or maybe should I say very incomplete) answer. I very much appreciated it.

Comment: @rschwieb As O.L. explained (@O.L. thank you for that), it was supposed to be a quick fix. I saw that the accepted answer had a wrong conclusion in the comments, and rushed to correct it. O.L. then edited his answer, so there was no need for me to give a mathematical way to solve it, especially since it would be very close to what his current answer is.